# Java User's Name and Reverse Order

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a code for class and I can't seem to find the error. Every time I run the code through Dr. Java, I am hit with a NullPointer exception.The code is supposed to take a users input and reverse the order of it. Any help? This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class LoopsProgram 
{ 
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    { 
        Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println ("What is your name?"); 

        String nameOfPerson = stringScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(nameOfPerson); 
        int lengthOfName = nameOfPerson.length (); 
        char beginning = nameOfPerson.charAt(lengthOfName); 
        for (int i = lengthOfName-1; i > 0; i--) { 
            beginning = nameOfPerson.charAt(i); 
            System.out.print(beginning); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: you can go through this website. http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/12/5-ways-to-reverse-string-in-java-with-example.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To help you get the most out of this site, please read our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and rework your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char beginning = nameOfPerson.charAt(lengthOfName);` - you are trying to access the 5th index, where as it will have index from 0 to 4. That's why you are getting errors.

Try this below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("What is your name?");

        String nameOfPerson = stringScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Name : "+nameOfPerson+" & length : "+nameOfPerson.length());
        int lengthOfName = nameOfPerson.length();
        String result = "";
        for (int i = lengthOfName-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result+=nameOfPerson.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. char beginning = nameOfPerson.charAt(lengthOfName);
2. for (int i = lengthOfName-1; i > 0; i--)

In Java index starts from 0 so the last character index will be lengthOfName-1. **Issue 1**

For loop will not include character at index zero as we have condition (i>0). It should be i>=0. **Issue 2**

Comment: @halim, guy is expecting root cause(I suppose).